# Multiple video tags in same page swapping video among each other

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am using `<video>` tags to show multiple videos on my web page. 
Videos are playing randomly with different tags. Video of one tag is playing in another video tag other attributes of `<video>` tag remain proper, only content of the video swap with others

```
<video id={"video-"+ this.props._id}  width="100%" controls preload="metadata" poster={this.props.poster}>
    <source src={this.props.url} type="video/mp4 " />
</video>
```

There are multiple such videos and all play randomly. In inspect element URL and other attribute are fine. 
Using Preact. 
Why is this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with help of one guy. 
I reloaded the video src, below code works fine for me

```
ComponentDidUpdate(){
  let video_el = document.getElementById("<video-element-id>") // get reference
  video_el.src = new_src // change src
  video_el.load() // <-- bug fix
}
```